# Problem with floating sidenotes in CSS

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying out floating sidenotes that cut into the main body of a text. You can see what I have so far [here](http://www.dinkypage.com/118065) and (as a jsfiddle) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ffYEK/2/).

I am having trouble with two constraints I am trying to simultaneously satisfy:

- Make the sidenotes line up with the in-text citation: e.g., the superscript '1' in the main text and the superscript '1' in the sidenote should line up horizontally.
- Give the sidenotes the padding they need, so that any lines of main text that run into the padding are shortened.

Currently, I am satisfying the second constraint, but this keeps me from satisfying the first constraint. Does anyone know how to satisfy both at once? Thanks!

EDIT: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArkSR.png)'s a little image illustrating the basic idea. I just want something like behaves like old-fashioned sidenotes, in old texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `top` style to your `floatnote` rule:

```
floatnote {
    position: relative;
    background:white;
    top:-20px;  // ADD THIS
    padding: 20px 0px 10px 15px;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    clear: right;
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/ffYEK/3/

*Only tested in Chrome*

Comment: I've tried that, but unfortunately (as you can see) it obscures the main text.

Comment: @Hans57 just take the background color off it. Also i would remove sdnote nodes and replace css with: `floatnote{
    counter-increment: sdnote;
    text-indent: 0px;}
floatnote:before{
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    top: -0.6em;
    padding-left: 2px;
    font-size: 10px;
    content: counter(sdnote);}` This will simplify your markup (take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/ffYEK/4/)

Comment: @Hans57 there are other improvements like add to `floatnote:before`: `padding-right: 4px;` so you then don't need extra spaces in your markup. Once you have it working right i would suggest [codereview.se] to see if anyone can help optomise your css html

Comment: @JamesKhoury I've tried that as well, but then the top padding does nothing, which means the above line isn't shortened. Does that make sense? Thanks.

Comment: @hans57 no sorry I didn't understand. Changing the background color shouldn't affect the padding. Did you check out that jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ffYEK/4

Comment: @JamesKhoury I mean that the line above the notes should be shortened by the padding. For example, in your jsfiddle, the sentence beginning "Mauris..." should be shortened at the word "turpis".

Comment: @Hans57 ... Then just change `top` to `top: -10px;` or something more to your liking?

Comment: @JamesKhoury But then the superscripts don't line up anymore and we're back to square one: http://jsfiddle.net/ffYEK/5/

Comment: @Hans57 You don't seem to understand how HTML works. You have the sidenote in the flow of text it renders from there downwards, not upwards.

Comment: @JamesKhoury Then is there any way to relocate the sidenote so that the superscripted numeral occurring in it lines up horizontally with the in-text citation, and with its margins extending to the immediate line above the in-text citation as well? Thanks.

Comment: @Hans57 not with css you'd be looking for a javascript solution. google: `css sidenotes` or `html sidenotes`